# How to keep data saved when switching between activities in Android

Tags: java, android

I'm a beginner at Android Studio but I have been trying to build a game app for my school project. In it the players can access their score at any point of time. I show scores in a different activity but when I come back to my main activity the scores reset themselves (back to the value I declared them with).

I have tried intent,saved instances and shared preferences but none of them worked (or maybe I'm using them wrong).

names_activity (Main)

```
int scorea=0;
int scoreb=0;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_names_);

    mscr=(Button)findViewById(R.id.scrs);
    mta=(Button)findViewById(R.id.ta);
    mtb=(Button)findViewById(R.id.tb);
    mta.setEnabled(false);
    mtb.setEnabled(false);

    mTextView=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.fmname);
    mButton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.spin);

    mButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            showRandom();
            mta.setEnabled(true);
            mtb.setEnabled(true);
            mta.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    scorea++;
                    mta.setEnabled(false);
                    mtb.setEnabled(false);
                    mButton.setEnabled(true);


                }
            });
            mtb.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                    scoreb++;
                    mta.setEnabled(false);
                    mtb.setEnabled(false);
                    mButton.setEnabled(true);
                }
            });

        }

    });
    mscr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(names_Activity.this,scores_Activity.class);

            intent.putExtra("scoreA",Integer.toString(scorea));
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });

}
```

vars scorea scoreb save scores of team A and team B when I switch to scores_activity and return to names_activity (main) the scores reset to 0

Second activity (displays scores)

```
public class scores_Activity extends AppCompatActivity {
private TextView mtas;
private TextView mtbs;
private Button mback;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_scores_);
    Intent intent=getIntent();
    mback=(Button)findViewById(R.id.back);
    mtas = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tas);
    mtbs = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.tbs);
    String scorea= intent.getStringExtra("scoreA");
    mtas.setText(scorea);
    mback.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {

            Intent intent=new Intent(scores_Activity.this,names_Activity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });


}
}
```

Comment: Hi, you must provide code in order for us to help you more

Comment: @AlanDeep I have edited the post  and provided the code

Answer (score 0):

Like @alan-deep said, it's kinda hard to understand with no code at all. But if I could understand, you need this: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/activities/activity-lifecycle

It depends on what paused/destroyed your activity, so you might as well try:
A) `onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState)` then `onRestoreInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState)` or `onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)`

```
// invoked when the activity may be temporarily destroyed, save the instance state here
@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    outState.putString(GAME_STATE_KEY, gameState);
    outState.putString(TEXT_VIEW_KEY, textView.getText());

    // call superclass to save any view hierarchy
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

B) SharedPreferences. If you can't restore your data using android's lifecycle, try [This approach](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared-preferences).

C) Sometimes your data become more complex so you start to need some more complex structures and relationships. In this case, you might want to use a [local database](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/room?hl=en).